# wxwidget overloaded functions "wxToolbar::Addtool"

Tags: visual-c++

Good day.

I'm working on a GUI application using WxWidget in Visual Studio 2017. I've encountered this error:

> No instance of overloaded functions "wxToolbar::Addtool"matches  the
>   argumentlist argument are: (wxStandardID, wxBitmap,conts wchar_t[17] object type is : wxToolbar)

I had managed to bring down the errors from twenty-five to six, but the error above doesn't go away
 (I've claned and restarted my IDE). The code below is where the issue is occurring:

```
wxToolBar *toolbar = CreateToolBar();
toolbar->AddTool(wxID_EXIT, exit, wxT("Exit application"));
toolbar->Realize();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Wxwidget version you are programming with is >2.9. Looking the [documentation](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=34858),
the method for parameter overloading :  toolbar1->AddTool(wxID_ANY, save, wxT(""));  had been deprecated, would advice  you study [this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tool_bar.html#a487ba33ad14dd9fe6cb8c29a71d31d4f) before  you start coding.

Happy coding.